# Json post object values always getting null in .net core 3.1

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am passing the JSON object from the postman with values. But while debugging, always object values getting null.

object :
{
"Key": "key1",
"Number": "",
"b": [
{
"amt": null
}
]
}

Model :

```
    public class A
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public List<B> b { get; set; }
    } 
    public class B
    {
        public decimal amt { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller :

[image]

StartUp:

```
        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(c =>
        {
            c.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
            c.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;                
        });
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
        services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializeAndFormat();
        });
```

Comment: Don't post image of code, poste code instead : http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: can you share the objects used at both client and server?

Comment: Hi azharuddin irfani, I updated the question with both client and server objects.

Comment: The object is not null, the problem is that the fields aren't serializing. Given the used names that's probably where the issue is. In the C# class use capitals: Key, Number, B and Amt. And in the json start fieldnames with lowercase: { "key": "key1", "number": "", "b": [ { "amt": null } ] }

Comment: I tried by giving the same case of properties in Model and Object. But still getting the same issue.
object : {"Key":"key1","Number":"","B":[{"Amt":null}]}
Model : 
public class A
        {
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public List<B> B { get; set; }
        }
        public class B
        {
            public decimal Amt { get; set; }
        }

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine by implementing the model state validations at the view models and using the [fromBody] at the controller method calling level.

```
    public IActionResult GeData([FromBody] requestModel)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(_commonApplicationService.MigrateControlCode());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```